# Similar Triangles in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In rectangle MATH, line MA=8 and line AT=9. Z is on AT with AZ=6, W is on MH with HW=4. Line WT intersects line MZ at Y.

X is on MH and YX is perpendicular to MX. What is the length of XY?

Comment: What have you tried? This is definitely brute-forcable with coordinate geometry, so what is the answer?

Comment: I am stuck in the perpendicular part of YX and MX since I cannot create a perpendicularity between the two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangles YMW and YZT are similar and we can write:

$\frac{ZT}{MW}=\frac{SY}{SY+8}$

$\frac{3}{5}=\frac{SY}{SY+8}$

Which gives $SY=12$, where S is intersection of extension of AT and XY. So:

$XY=SY+SX=12+8=20$